# How to count coloured cells in a DrawGrid?

Tags: delphi, drawing, cells

I use the TDrawGrid component to paint a grid. 46Y x 70X

[image]

If i select a cell it will be coloured with `clGrey` and if i select it again it will be coloured in White again. I want to count all `clGrey` couloured Cells.

My following code is what i tried, but didnt worked.

```
procedure TForm2.RasterDrawGridSelectCell(Sender: TObject; ACol, ARow: Integer;
  var CanSelect: Boolean);
begin
  UniversumsMatrix[ACol, ARow] := not UniversumsMatrix[ACol, ARow];

    begin
    if RasterDrawGrid.Brush.Color = clGrey then begin
      Zellenstand := Zellenstand - 1
    end
    else
      Zellenstand := Zellenstand +1 ;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm2.RasterDrawGridDrawCell(Sender: TObject; ACol, ARow: Integer;
  Rect: TRect; State: TGridDrawState);
begin
  if UniversumsMatrix[ACol, ARow] then
    RasterDrawGrid.Canvas.Brush.Color := clGray // Grauer der lebendigen Hintergrund
  else
    RasterDrawGrid.Canvas.Brush.Color := clWhite; // Weißer Hintergrund
    RasterDrawGrid.Canvas.FillRect(Rect);
end;
```

Comment: Zellenstand is the sum of  UniversumsMatrix[ACol, ARow] with value true. Since you seem to plan a kind of lifetime RasterDrawGridSelectCell won't be the best place to count living cells.

Comment: Apart from what bummi said, why do you try to control it based on the color when you already have a boolean indicating if the cell is alive or not?

Comment: U mean the solution is much more easier? Just counting the true array elements?

Comment: You're already counting the sum (in `Zellenstand` variable), you're just using wrong property to determine if a cell is selected or not. The [`Brush`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.Brush) property is for something else and is not even related to cells. Since you're having array of states, you should definitely ask that array what is the state of a cell and increase or decrease `Zellenstand` accordingly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A more efficent way of handling the counter would be wrapping the array in a class with according setter and getter, and accessing the array only via setters and getters.

```
Type
  TUniverseClass = Class
  Private
    FArray: Array [0 .. 71, 0 .. 45] of Boolean;
    FLivingCount: Integer;
    function GetXY(X, Y: Integer): Boolean;
    procedure SetXY(X, Y: Integer; const Value: Boolean);
  Public
    Property XYValue[X, Y: Integer]: Boolean Read GetXY Write SetXY;
    Property LivingCount: Integer Read FLivingCount;

  End;

var
  UniverseClass: TUniverseClass;

  { UniverseClass }

function TUniverseClass.GetXY(X, Y: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  Result := FArray[X, Y];
end;

procedure TUniverseClass.SetXY(X, Y: Integer; const Value: Boolean);
begin
  if FArray[X, Y] <> Value then
    if Value then
      Inc(FLivingCount)
    else
      Dec(FLivingCount);
  FArray[X, Y] := Value;
end;
// example call
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  UniverseClass.XYValue[0, 0] := true;
  Memo1.Lines.Add(IntToStr(UniverseClass.LivingCount));
  UniverseClass.XYValue[1, 1] := true;
  Memo1.Lines.Add(IntToStr(UniverseClass.LivingCount));
  UniverseClass.XYValue[0, 0] := false;
  Memo1.Lines.Add(IntToStr(UniverseClass.LivingCount));

end;

initialization

UniverseClass := TUniverseClass.Create;

finalization

UniverseClass.Free;
```

Comment: +1 This is much more like it. Step 1, separate logic into single responsibility classes instead of globbing everything into a GUI form!

Comment: Definitely better than my answer, so I deleted it

Answer (score 3):

It looks that in UniversumsMatrix you already have Boolean values. Just calculate True or False values.

Answer (score 1):

UniversumsMatrix is filled by you. Why don't you have a Sum variable which is increased when you set a value to TRUE? You wouldn't even have to bother counting cells in a drawgrid?